# ¿Como puedo pasar los datos de jframe a una clase para realizar operaciones y despues regresar el resultado al jframe?

Tags: java, poo, interfaz-gráfica, set

En esta clase tengo las operaciones

```
public class Calculadora1 {
private float n1;
private float n2;

public Calculadora1() {
}

public Calculadora1(float n1, float n2) {
    this.n1 = n1;
    this.n2 = n2;
}

public float sumar(){
    float suma= this.n1 + this.n2;
   return suma;
}
 public float resta(){
    float resta= this.n1 - this.n2;
   return resta;
}
 public float dividir(){
    float dividir= this.n1 / this.n2;
   return dividir;    
}
```

como puedo pasar los valores  mi Jframe a la clase donde se realizaran las operaciones y como muestro el resultado en jframe
[image: esta es mi interfaz de una calculadora]

Answer (score 1):

Primero... tienes que darle a cada boton una accion eso lo haces con implements ActionListener, segundo se recomienda usar MVC, al tener el mvc le das a cada boton un valor en Sring que llega al controlador y este lo pasas a numerico, cada click en la calculadora sera un actionEvent, estos strings que llegan al controlador se convierten en int en el modelo y se van sumando en una clase del modelo, posteriormente cuando se de un actionEvent de tipo suma multiplicacion o resta usaras los datos traidos del modelo (Nuestro numero actual) y se haga la operacion correspondiente al dar el evento '=' se colocara el dato traido del modelo que da el resultado de la operacion de esta forma: `formVistaCalculadora.getTxtRespuesta().setText(""+objetoModeloOperacion.getResultado);`

para crear un actionevent se hace de esta forma:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

private FormularioCalculadora formVistaCalculadora;
  public ControladorMenu()  {
formVistaCalculadora= new FormularioCalculadora();
formVistaCalculadora.getBtnNum1.addActionListener(this);//asi habilitas el boton para actionListener.
}
    if (e.getSource()==formVistaCalculadora.getBtnNum1()) { //asi creas lo que se hara cuando se de un click al boton.
string valor= objCalcu.getTxtnum1().getText();  
}
```

}